# How did he simplify this problem like this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\left(\frac{x}{12}+\frac{x}{18}\right)t=x$$

$$\left(\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{18}\right)t=1$$

I want a solid rule, how did he simplify the problem in the image like this!

Comment: Or you may prefer since division of a matrix by a scalar in my experience isn't really define, multiply both sides by 1/x (still with Moo's $x \ne 0$

Comment: Its labelled algebra-precalculus people. Lets write comments at that level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If
$$\left(\frac{x}{12}+\frac{x}{18}\right)t=x\tag{1}$$
then in general it is *not* true that
$$\left(\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{18}\right)t=1\tag{2}$$
**Counterexample**: if $t=36$ and $x=0$, then you see that $(1)$ is equivalent to $0=0$ which is true, but $(2)$ is equivalent to $5=1$ which is *not*.

**However**, if you already know that $x\neq0$, then the implication is true since in that case
$$
\left(\frac{x}{12}+\frac{x}{18}\right)t=x
$$
is equivalent to (this is just a factorization)
$$
\left(\left(\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{18}\right)t\right)x=x
$$
and 
you can divide both sides (which are equal, after all!) by $x$ (since $x\neq0$... otherwise division by $0$ doesn't make sense!) to maintain equality and infer
$$
\frac{\left(\left(\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{18}\right)t\right)x}{x}=\frac{x}{x}
$$
which is the same as
$$
\left(\left(\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{18}\right)t\right)\frac{x}{x}=\frac{x}{x}
$$
or, since $\frac{x}{x}=1$ always,
$$
\left(\left(\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{18}\right)t\right)\cdot1=1
$$
that is
$$
\left(\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{18}\right)t=1
$$

Of course, at a certain level of mathematical maturity, all of these intermediate steps are very rarely all written out since they should be obvious.

---

Note that if you have
$$
\left(\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{18}\right)t=1\tag{3}
$$
then it must *always* be true that
$$
\left(\frac{x}{12}+\frac{x}{18}\right)t=x
$$
(just multiply both sides of $(3)$ by $x$... this will always be a valid operation, unlike division by an *a priori* **arbitrary** real number $x$ which is not valid if $x=0$).

---

In fact, a well-known false proof that $2=1$ makes use of an *invalid* division by $0$.

Suppose that $x=y\neq0$. Then
\begin{align}
x^2&=xy\\
x^2-y^2&=xy-y^2\\
(x+y)(x-y)&=y(x-y)\\
x+y&=y\\
2y&=y\\
2&=1
\end{align}
right? No! From
$$
(x+y)(x-y)=y(x-y)\tag{4}
$$
you can't infer that
$$
x+y=y
$$
because dividing both sides of $(4)$ by $(x-y)$ and simplifying doesn't make sense since $x-y=0$.

Comment: Might be clearer to the OP to start with demonstrating why it works then go to the caveat that it only works for $x\ne0$.

Comment: @Ian Miller Well, since dividing by $x$ is essentially the first step, you must be aware of the limitations of this operation *before* applying it...

Comment: You could also argue that if it is only going to occur in a very small number of cases that you could add a warning about it after it.

Comment: @Ian Miller Whatever, I'm no pedagogue. I just wanted to emphasize that the implication is not true.